# Creating a new matrix with mean values from an array of matrices

Tags: arrays, matrix, mean

I have an array of values from procrustes transcribed data and I'm trying to create two new matrices with the means of select matrices from the original array.

Comment: Make a better example. and what language?

Comment: Sorry, as you can guess I'm very new to everything. I'm using R. 

testmx<-array(NA,dim=c(nlmk,3,9))
for (i in 1:9){
  testmx[,,i]<-matrix((sup$rotated)[((i+10)*datapoints-(datapoints-6)):((i+10)*datapoints)], ncol=3 , byrow=T)

}

so for this array i have selected procrustes data from a subset of a previous array (sup$rotated) What I need now is to determine how to get the mean each element [x,y,z] from the matrices in the new array, and have that in its own separate matrix.